# Can reading a variable be a data race in OpenMP?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

Why does this OpenMP fortran program work (every element of `out` is equal to `num`)? Each thread in the parallel loop might read the variable `num` simultaneously. I thought this was not acceptable?

```
  program example
    implicit none
    integer i
    integer, parameter :: n = 100000
    double precision :: num
    double precision, dimension(n) :: out

    num = 1.123456789123456789123456d-5
    out = 0.d0

    !$OMP PARALLEL
    !$OMP DO
    do i=1,n
      out(i) = num
    enddo
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL

    do i=1,n
      if (out(i).ne.num) print*,'Problem with ',i
    enddo

  end program
```

Thanks so much for any insights.

Answer (score 3):

> Can reading a variable be a data race in OpenMP?

Any race is between two things happening, so a read can be part of a race. However for the competition between two actions to be a race, there has to be a different outcome depending on the order in which the two actions occur.
Given that the possible actions in a parallel program which we are considering are read and write occurring in different threads, we have four possible cases:

1. Read, Read: no values are changed, and no code can detect which order the two reads occurred in (at least, not without looking at meta-data such as code performance in a system with caches :-)).

2. Read, Write: this clearly can be a race; whether the write wins the race or not affects the value which will be read.
3. Write, Read: as with case 2 (Read,Write), the result seen by the read is affected by the order.
4. Write, Write: here we have a race too, since we *asssume* that someone will ultimately read the value, and which value they see will depend on the order of the writes.

So, reading a variable can be part of a race.
However, if your question is really "Is there a race if a variable is only read?", then the answer is "No".

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my question would have been better phrased as "Is there a race if a variable is only read?". And the answer is no, as you said

Answer (score 2):

Variables are shared by default in openMP so they are accessible from all the threads. Furthermore, you're not writing to `num` so even if all the threads were accessing the same memory (which here they probably aren't) there would be no issue.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on this: "even if all the threads were accessing the same memory (which is implementation defined) there would be no issue". What do you mean by "implementation defined"? Why is it OK for simultaneous reading of `num`?

Comment: Hi, well, I was just thinking about data locality. Usually for shared variables, the same address is passed to the threads. But here "num" could be totally inlined as it's a double and you're never changing if so then it doesn't have a shared address.  [This](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/cuppvars.htm) explains the implicit sharing attribues